# Python - How to check wordpress site version

Tags: python, wordpress

I am thinking about fetching the wordpress version installed on a domain but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're possibly looking to do is called scraping.  [RealPython](https://realpython.com) has a great explanation of how to use one of the most common web scrapers for python, [BeautifulSoup](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/)

What you will need to find in the HTML is something like this:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.6">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the RSS Feed. Just add `/feed` to the end of the site’s URL. Press ctrl+F to bring up page search, and type in “generator”. You can find it near the top of the page.

Here you’ll see something like “https://wordpress.org/?v=x.x.x”. And there’s your version number! You can have a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/) to scrape the generator tag and get the version number.

[image: Sample]